# 英語がまだ残っている箇所をおしえてください

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

以下の場所で英語がまだ残っています：

1. メインサイトのバナー
   [image: スクリーンショット]
2. 一番下のサイトリスト
   [image: スクリーンショット]
3. 一番下のリンク（[ブログ](http://blog.stackexchange.com/?blb=1)、[チャット](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)、[法律](http://stackexchange.com/legal)、[プライバシー・ポリシー](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy)、[ここで機能する](http://stackexchange.com/work-here)、[広告情報](http://stackexchange.com/mediakit)）

**上記以外の箇所** で英語を見つけたら、スタック・オーバーフローMetaにて[質問を投稿してください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%8C%E6%AE%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B:%20&tags=%E3%83%90%E3%82%B0+%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3+%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E)。

**こちらのタグを適用してください：**

[バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0)[翻訳](/questions/tagged/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3)[英語](/questions/tagged/%e8%8b%b1%e8%aa%9e)

スクリーンショットもあると助かります。正しい日本語も添えていただけると最高です。

ご協力よろしくお願い致します！

Comment: 「質問を投稿してください」のリンクについて: URLのパラメータを使うことで、あらかじめタグとタイトルを指定できます: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%8C%E6%AE%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B:%20&tags=%E3%83%90%E3%82%B0+%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3+%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E

Answer (score 2):

ヘルプセンターに英語が残っています.(2014/10/7現在)

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: やっぱり・・・[今日ヘルプセンターを更新した](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240594/proposed-new-code-of-conduct-for-all-stack-exchange-sites)ため、自動的に全サイトに適用してしまいました。困りますね！リストに入れますが、すぐ改善できることは不可能です（翻訳が必要ため）。できれば、[新しい質問を投稿](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)すれば、管理しやすくなります。よろしくお願いします！

Comment: @jmac 混乱させてしまいすいません、これからは、新しい質問として投稿します。

Answer (score 2):

質問を「閉じる」を押すとでるページに英語が残っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: データベースには「この質問は、$Topic$ についてヘルプ センターで定義されている範囲から外れているようです。」が書いてありますが、適用されていないようですね。開発者と確認してみます。上記の日本語がおかしかったら、ご教示ください。