# スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ

Tags: サポート, プライベートベータ

#### 日本語が母国語の皆様へ、スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版へようこそ！

Stack Overflowの目的はプログラミングに関しての質問すべてに回答を提供する事ですが、残念ながら英語版のみでは全ての方に回答を読んで頂くことが出来ず、その目的を達成することが出来ません。

2013年12月にポルトガル語版を立ち上げ、この度、日本語版の立ち上げに挑戦することになりました。現在ポルトガル語版はベータ版を卒業することに決まっています！

現在日本語版はプライベートベータです。パブリックベータになるまでの一番重要な点は：

1. **質問を投稿すること**　質問がないとエキスパートのみなさんが回答できませんので、回答が分かっていても、投稿してみんなと共有しましょう！
2. **投票すること**　当サイトの管理はみんなで行うため、[権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)をできるだけ多くの人が持っていることが必要です。投票すると点が入って権限が増えていきますので、できるだけ投票しましょう！
3. **回答を投稿すること**　[未回答の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)の回答を優先するのがベストですが、回答済みの質問でもさらなる回答で役立つ情報を提供できれば他のプログラマーを助けることができます。

ご支援ありがとうございます。100件の質問を目指しましょう！

Comment: 既に同じ指摘が上がっているかどうかを確認したいのですが、サイトの検索メニューを使っても、検索することが出来ません。まだ検索機能は使えない状態なのでしょうか？

Comment: @tomute、開発者と確認したところ、検索ソフトは英語中心に作っているため、日本語等のローマ字意外は検索できない状況です。検索ソフトの更新は計画していますが、ちょっと時間がかかります。大変恐縮ですが、ご了承ください。

Comment: 承知しました。検索ソフトが日本語に対応されるのをお待ちしております。

Comment: Googleで検索できるようになればそれでいいと思いますが、Googleのインデックスに載るのは今は止めていますよね？

Answer (score 3):

基本的な使い方の紹介。

回答へのUpvoteや解決済みへのマーク、質問のガイドラインなどのポリシーを伝える必要があると思います。
質問も回答もしない人はまずはUpvote/Downvoteをすることから始めて、よい質問、よい回答を学ぶのがいいかなと。

またエンジニア向けの外部媒体などでの使い方紹介など宣伝も検討したほうがいいと思います。

Comment: メタで「faq」のようにその操作方法を投稿してくれませんか？それを注目させることができますので、役に立つと思います。

Answer (score 1):

#### 翻訳の改善

日本語版はまだ始まったばかりで、まだまだ完成とはいえません。特に翻訳には問題が多く、あちこちに英語がまだ残っていますし、日本語に関するバグも多少あります。

現段階での目的は3つあります：

1. [英語が残っている箇所を洗い出す](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3/%e8%8b%b1%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%8c%e3%81%be%e3%81%a0%e6%ae%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e7%ae%87%e6%89%80)
   → [新しく投稿する](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%8C%E6%AE%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B:%20&tags=%E3%83%90%E3%82%B0+%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3+%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E)
2. [日本語に違和感がある箇所を洗い出す](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4/%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%ab%e9%81%95%e5%92%8c%e6%84%9f%e3%81%ae%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e7%ae%87%e6%89%80)
   → [新しく投稿する](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F:%20&tags=%E3%83%90%E3%82%B0+%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3+%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E)
3. [全般的によりよく改善できる箇所を洗い出す](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5/%e5%bd%93%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e6%94%b9%e5%96%84%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81%e3%81%ae%e6%8f%90%e6%a1%88)

この目的を達成するために、今ご覧になっているサイト「[スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)」を利用します。

もちろんメインサイトで実際のプログラミングに関する質問を聞いたり答えたりしていただいてもよいですし、テスト環境として扱っていただいてもOKです。新しいユーザーを招待する前に、テストとして使ったポストを掃除する予定ですが、本当の質問や回答を削除するつもりはありませんので、自由に利用してください！

バグや問題点を洗い出せたら、翻訳会社に修正を頼み、スタック・オーバーフローの英語版をご存知ではないユーザーにも紹介し始めます。現時点ではスケジュールは決まっていませんが、その時期が近づいたら具体的な流れを共有させていただきます。

ご協力よろしくお願いします！

Answer (score 1):

#### 専門用語の改善

Stack Overflowは専門用語が多いです。「Upvote」、「Closed Question」等の専門用語がヘルプをはじめとしてすべての質問・回答ページに出てきます。一つ一つを更新するより、専門用語の訳語を確定させてからサイト全体への適用を翻訳会社に頼むつもりです。

そのため、まず専門用語を確定させないといけないです。下記のメタ投稿をご覧の上、適切な日本語の案出し・話し合いをお願いします。**来週の金曜日に**翻訳会社に渡したいので、ご協力よろしくお願いします。

- [Stack Overflowの専門用語](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/)
- [メタの既にあるタグ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/16/)

他にもよく出てくる言葉があれば、専門用語のリストを編集して追加するか、メタで質問として投稿していただければリストを更新します。

Answer (score 1):

#### Stack Overflowメインサイトでの質問投稿

当サイトはQ&Aサイトですから、質問や回答がないとあまり役に立ちません。招待ユーザーを増やしていきますので、プログラミングに関しての質問があったら、[メインサイトに投稿してください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)。質問が思い浮かばない場合、[英語のStack Overflowの人気タグ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)の質問を投稿しても良いです。

もちろん、質問や回答投稿中に問題点等を見つけたら、[メタにて投稿をお願いします](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)。