# Stack Overflowの専門用語を統一したい

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, 専門用語

**注意！**　この投稿はサイト設立当時に専門用語の和訳を決めようとしたものです。現在最新の専門用語一覧は [スタック・オーバーフロー 専門用語の和訳一覧](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3502/19110) で管理されています。

---

Stack Overflowの専門用語は多いです。現在の翻訳はバラバラで、専門用語を統一する必要があります。下記は現在の（バラバラ）和訳です：

```
　　　　　　　英語　　　　　　　　　　現在の和訳
(名詞) Vote               ：投票
(動詞) Vote               ：投票する
(名詞) Upvote             ：賛成投票
(動詞) Upvote             ：賛成投票する
(名詞) Downvote           ：反対投票
(動詞) Downvote           ：反対投票する
(名詞) Close Vote         ：クローズ投票
(動詞) Vote to Close      ：クローズ投票する
(名詞) Flag               ：通報
(動詞) Flag               ：通報する
(名詞) Closed Question    ：クローズされた質問
(動詞) Close a Question   ：質問をクローズする
(名詞) Bounty             ：お礼
(動詞) Bounty             ：お礼をあげる
(動詞) Start Bounty       ：お礼をあげる
(名詞) Reputation         ：信用度
(名詞) Reputation Change  ：信用度の変化
(名詞) Reputation Increase：信用度増加
(名詞) Reputation Decrease：信用度減少
(名詞) Suggested Edit     ：推奨される編集
(名詞) tag synonyms       ：タグ シノニム   
(名詞) suggested          ：推奨済み
(名詞) newest             ：新着
(名詞) active             ：アクティブ
(名詞) merge              ：マージ
(名詞) master             ：マスター
(名詞) synonym            ：シノニム
(名詞) creator            ：作成者
(名詞) renames            ：名前変更の回数
(名詞) last               ：最後
(名詞) pending            ：承認待ち
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

下記の表の通りに固めようと思っています。

間違いがあれば、コメントする、又は直接編集してください。

10月31日に固定しますので、今週中にコメントください。

```
　　　　　　　英語　　　　　　　　　　提案のまとめ
(名詞) Vote               ：投票
(動詞) Vote               ：投票する
(名詞) Upvote             ：プラス投票
(動詞) Upvote             ：プラス投票する
(名詞) Downvote           ：マイナス投票
(動詞) Downvote           ：マイナス投票する
(動詞) Accept             ：ベストアンサーを選ぶ
(名詞) Accepted Answer    ：ベストアンサー
(名詞) Close Vote         ：クローズ票
(動詞) Vote to Close      ：クローズ投票する
(前置詞句) On Hold         ：改善待ち
(名詞) Flag               ：通報
(動詞) Flag               ：通報する
(名詞) Closed Question    ：クローズされた質問
(動詞) Close a Question   ：質問をクローズする
(名詞) Bounty             ：お礼
(動詞) Bounty             ：お礼をあげる
(動詞) Start Bounty       ：お礼を提示する
(名詞) Reputation         ：信用度
(名詞) Reputation Change  ：信用度の変化
(名詞) Reputation Increase：信用度の増加
(名詞) Reputation Decrease：信用度の減少
(名詞) Suggested Edit     ：提案された編集[内容]/編集案
(動詞) Suggest an Edit    ：編集を提案する
(名詞) tag synonyms       ：別名タグ   
(名詞) synonym            ：別名   
(名詞) suggested          ：投票待ち
(名詞) newest             ：新着
(名詞) active             ：有効
(名詞) merge              ：マージ待ち
(名詞) master             ：正式名
(名詞) synonym            ：同義
(名詞) creator            ：作成者
(名詞) renames            ：置換回数
(名詞) last               ：最終更新
(名詞) pending            ：投票待ち
(名詞) peer review        ：レビュー
(動詞) place in a queue   ：レビュー待ちになる
(名詞) privileges         ：権限
```

Comment: 遅ればせながら。「ベストアンサー」について、「質問者が選んだ回答であって、一番よい答えではないかもしれない」というニュアンスをどうにか出せないかな、と思います。英語版SOで、accepted answerの内容が古かったりして、別の回答がもっと票を集めている状況をよく目にします。そういう時にたとえば「マイベストアンサー」などの名前であれば齟齬がないと思います。どうでしょか

Comment: @ento 投稿者のおすすめ回答？できれば短い方がいいですが、ニュアンスつたえるのも大事ですから、短くてわかりやすい案はありますか？

Comment: 「花まるアンサー」: 主観的、というニュアンスは出ると思います。好き嫌いは分かれるような気がします。

Comment: @ento 実施しました。それはいいですね。アイコンも変えましょうかな？

Comment: 花マルだとUnicodeにありますね「」、赤文字「㊝」とかもわかりやすいかも。個人的にはSOで慣れてしまったので星の方が好きですが…

Comment: @emix 残念ながら、ほとんどのブラウザがUnicodeの花まるをサポートしないので、それは多分難しいと思いますが、当社ではデザイナーがいるので、必要に応じて作成することは可能です。

Comment: 花まるアンサーって言われてもこういうところで耳慣れない単語過ぎて驚いてしまいますね。他のQAサイトであるような、ベストアンサーというニュアンスがもっとよく伝わること言葉があればいいのですが

Comment: 私もNishikawaさんと同感で、花まるアンサーというのは相当な違和感を感じます。少しOff-topicですが、`花まる`という単語は小学生以降触れることが無いため、幼稚に感じてしまいます。日本人に馴染み深い知恵袋系サイトにおいての用例も鑑みると、やはり`ベストアンサー`が一番しっくりきます。
「あくまで質問者が選んだもの」というニュアンスを伝えることについて、先ほど私が立てた[翻訳忘れ報告](http://goo.gl/t1Rhzj)で指摘した緑のチェックマークをポイントした際のポップアップには原文の時点でその旨が記載されています。ですから、そこを翻訳してポップアップさせれば`ベストアンサー`でも問題ないのではないかなとは思います。

Comment: みなさん「ベストアンサー」を自然に使っているようなので、やっぱりそれがよさそうですね。

Comment: @ento 上記のリストを翻訳者に送りますので、ミス・改善すべき点があればご教示ください。

Comment: [「お礼」は結構みんな違和感を持っている](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/163)ので (+5票がつく質問は今のところ中々ない)、変えるのを検討した方がよいと思います。あと「同義タグ」は言い方として固いような気がしてきたので、[独立した質問として登録](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/374/30)しました

Comment: 使用される文脈がわからないのですが "merge"=「マージ待ち」の理由はなんでしょう？（なぜ「待ち」？）

Comment: @yohjp 翻訳者に聞かないとわかりません。どうしてでしょう・・・

Comment: Acceptを納得、Accepted Answerを納得した回答というのはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

提案です。

```
(動詞) Start Bounty : お礼を提示する
```

「お礼を開始する」は日本語的に少し違和感があるので、提示するの方が良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

#### 提案があれば、下記に追加・編集お願いします！

```
　　　　　　　英語　　　　　　　　　　提案のまとめ
(名詞) Vote               ：投票
(動詞) Vote               ：投票する
(名詞) Upvote             ：Upvote／賛成投票／プラス投票
(動詞) Upvote             ：Upvoteする／賛成投票する／プラス投票する
(名詞) Downvote           ：Downvote／反対投票／マイナス投票
(動詞) Downvote           ：Downvoteする／反対投票する／マイナス投票する
(動詞) Accept             ：承認する／解決済みにする／ベストアンサーを選ぶ
(名詞) Accepted Answer    ：承認済みの回答／ベストアンサー
(名詞) Close Vote         ：クローズ票
(動詞) Vote to Close      ：クローズ投票する
(名詞) Flag               ：問題フラグ
(動詞) Flag               ：問題フラグを立てる／通報する
(名詞) Closed Question    ：クローズされた質問
(動詞) Close a Question   ：質問をクローズする
(名詞) Bounty             ：お礼／Bounty
(動詞) Bounty             ：お礼／Bountyをあげる
(動詞) Start Bounty       ：お礼を提示する／Bounty付ける
(名詞) Reputation         ：Reputation／信用度
(名詞) Reputation Change  ：Reputationの変化
(名詞) Reputation Increase：Reputationの増加
(名詞) Reputation Decrease：Reputationの減少
(名詞) Suggested Edit     ：編集リクエスト
(名詞) tag synonyms       ：タグ シノニム／タグの別名／同義のタグ／タグエイリアス   
(名詞) suggested          ：投票待ち
(名詞) newest             ：新着
(名詞) active             ：アクティブ／有効
(名詞) merge              ：マージ待ち
(名詞) master             ：マスター／正式名
(名詞) synonym            ：シノニム／別名／エイリアス
(名詞) creator            ：作成者
(名詞) renames            ：名前変更の回数
(名詞) last               ：最終更新
(名詞) pending            ：承認待ち／投票待ち
(名詞) peer review        ：ピアレビュー／レビュー
(動詞) place in a queue   ：レビュー待ちになる (文脈によって言いかえるのがよい)
```

Comment: これは Upvote や Downvote などの単語を別途説明することが前提ですか？そのままだと意味が分からないユーザは多いと思います。
もちろん、説明をしっかりすることにより、こちらから言葉を作っていくこともありかなとは思います。

Comment: @Daisuke、基本的に、ユーザーが読まない全体にした方がいいです。ヘルプをどんだけすばらしく書いても、9割以上の人は読まないのが現実です。「Upvote」のままで理解していないと、日本語訳の方がいいと思います。提案ありますか？

Comment: ほとんどのユーザーはヘルプを読まないという意見に賛成です。直感的に解る言葉を探したいですね。vote「投票する」という英単語を知らないユーザーも少なくないと思うので、英語で「Upvote」のままだと理解できない人もいると思います。そう考えると日本語の表記が望ましいですが、「賛成投票/反対投票」という訳にも違和感を感じます。ちょとおかしいかもしれませんが「Up投票/Down投票」とか「プラス投票/マイナス投票」というのも考えられるかもしれません。

Comment: @naota プラス投票・マイナス投票は個人的に好きです。シンプルで分かりやすいし、いいね！