# 英語が残っている箇所: プロフィールページの簡易表示

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URL例: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/30/ento

[image: reputation/badge]

reputation と badges: 訳語は [Stack Overflowの専門用語](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/stack-overflow%E3%81%AE%E5%B0%82%E9%96%80%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E) の結論にゆだねます。