# 日本語に違和感: この質問は次でお礼開始が可能でした

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

文脈: 自分の質問の下側に表示されるメッセージ

[image: この質問は次でお礼開始が可能でした]

Comment: 本件の翻訳の候補としては「お礼を提示する」とかどうでしょうか？

Comment: `question eligible for bounty $when$`は英語の文書（$when$は時間を示す変数）

Answer (score 0):

> [お礼の提示]は$when$から可能です
>
> 変数置換後の例: お礼の提示は2日後から可能です

[お礼の提示]は [Stack Overflowの専門用語](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/stack-overflow%E3%81%AE%E5%B0%82%E9%96%80%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E) が固まったらそちらに差し替えで。

ボツ案

- 2日後からお礼の提示ができます
- お礼の提示ができるのは2日後からです
- お礼の提示ができるようになるまで後2日