# 日本語に違和感: タグシノニム

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

「シノニム」が日本語では一般的でなく、分かりにくいと思います。[現在の専門用語訳案](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265/30)では「同義のタグ」となっていますが、こちらは言い方として固いように思います。

「エイリアス」も考えられますが、技術畑でないユーザーには分かりにくそうです。日本語版SOが成功したあかつきに、他の分野のQ&Aサイトを開設することを考慮すると、よい選択肢ではないように思います。

サイト内で「シノニム」が表示される箇所の例:

---

### [タグの詳細画面](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-app-engine/synonyms):

[image: タグ画面]

---

### [シノニム一覧画面](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms):

[image: 一覧]

Comment: この投稿の存在を知らずに別投稿してしまいました。そちらで変更が反映されたので、こちらもcompletedとします。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1851/8000

Answer (score 6):

「別名タグ」、「別名」はどうでしょうか。

> [google-app-engine](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine)の別名一覧 ： Tag synonyms for $tag$
>
> すべての別名タグを見る : see all tag synonyms
>
> 別名を提案する: : Suggest a $tag$ synonym:
>
> 別名タグ一覧 : Tag Synonyms (/tags/synonyms ページの見出し)
>
> 別名タグを登録する : /tags/synonyms の検索ボックスの横にあるリンク
>
> 正式名 ← 別名

Comment: 「別名」は解りやすいですね。"次のタグの別名: `google-app-engine`"の箇所ですが、もし言葉の順番を入れ替えることが可能なら、"`google-app-engine`の別名"のような語順の方がよいような気がします。

Comment: これを適用予定ですが、シノニムは複数箇所に出るため、[専門用語](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/stack-overflow%E3%81%AE%E5%B0%82%E9%96%80%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E)にたしてくれませんか？そのリストを利用してサイト全体を更新する予定ですので、わすれないようにそこに追加をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: @naota 語順を変える案、いただきました

Comment: @jmac 専門用語一覧を更新しました