# 「タグシノニム」という言葉を「タグの別名」に変えていこうと思います

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳

2014 年や 2015 年に、「タグシノニム」という専門用語が日本語として分かりにくいので「タグの別名」と呼ぶことにしよう、というメタ投稿があり、多数の支持を集めました。

- [日本語に違和感: タグシノニム](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374/19110)
- [用語の変更：「タグシノニム」を「タグの別名」に変えませんか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1851/19110)

このときはヘルプの文章が修正されたのですが、一方で「タグシノニム」という言葉は依然としてサイト内に散見されます。Traducir / Transifex に登録されている string だけでも現在 41 件も「シノニム」という言葉が残っています：https://ja.traducir.win/filters?translationRegex=%E3%82%B7%E3%83%8E%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A0

これらをひとつずつ「別名」に変えていこうと思うのですが、上記のメタ投稿から 5 年程度経ってしまっているため一度確認を挟んだ方が良いかもと思い、この投稿をしました。変えてしまって良ければプラス投票を、反対であればマイナス投票や理由の投稿をお願いしたいです。

Comment: メモ： https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms は中身は「タグの中身」なのにタイトルだけ「タグシノニム」になっている。

Comment: ↑いつの間にか英語に戻っていました :eyes:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aki さんのご協力により、Traducir 上で「シノニム」と訳されていたことが確認されていた string の数はゼロになりました。

ヘルプ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms の HTML title が訳されていない件は<del>作業中です。</del> → 翻訳されました！