# 用語の変更：「タグシノニム」を「タグの別名」に変えませんか？

Tags: 討議, 完了, 専門用語

このサイトにはタグシノニムという機能があります。

例えば、 Ruby on Rails というフレームワークは Rails という呼び名も一般的です。しかしこのサイト上で [ruby-on-rails](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) と [rails](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails) の二つのタグが混在してしまうと、検索が面倒になったり、タグに関連するバッジの判定がおかしくなってしまいます。

ここで [rails](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails) を [ruby-on-rails](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) のタグシノニムとして登録しておくと、 [rails](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails) が自動的に [ruby-on-rails](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) に置換されるようになり、同じ意味のタグが分散することを避けられます。

現在設定されているタグシノニムはタグ一覧の下部にある「タグシノニム」というリンクから一覧できます。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

参考 [ヘルプ センター > 権限 > タグ シノニムの作成](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

---

さて、「タグシノニム」という言葉を聞いてこの機能が想像できましたか？

メタ投稿「[Stack Overflowの専門用語](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11/8000)」では「別名タグ」という案が挙がっていますが、これを少しいじって、「タグの別名」という呼び方に変えるのはどうでしょうか？

これは他のメタ投稿にも言えることですが、ノーリアクションでは判断が付かないので

- 賛成：「タグの別名」に変えよう！という場合は**プラス投票**
- 反対：「タグシノニム」のまま、変える必要ない！という場合は**マイナス投票**

をぜひお願いします。

もし他の意見があれば**回答**に書いていただければ、そこでも投票が行えます！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

適用しました：

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

ご確認よろしくお願いします。