# 新しいメタタグの提案: [タグの別名の提案] と [タグの付け替えの提案]

Tags: 討議, タグ

コミュニティにタグの別名化をリクエストする際、今まではタイトルに「タグの別名の提案: 」などといったプレフィックスをつけていました。しかし過去に[「タグシノニム」が「タグの別名」に変わった](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1851/19110)こともあり、これだと検索性が悪くなっていました。

そんな中、Meta Stack Exchange には [[synonym-request]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonym-request/info) および [[retag-request]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/retag-request/info) というメタタグがあることを知りました。このタグは SOja Meta でも便利そうです。

そこで、過去の提案も含め [タグの別名の提案](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%bf%e3%82%b0%e3%81%ae%e5%88%a5%e5%90%8d%e3%81%ae%e6%8f%90%e6%a1%88) および [タグの付け替えの提案](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%bf%e3%82%b0%e3%81%ae%e4%bb%98%e3%81%91%e6%9b%bf%e3%81%88%e3%81%ae%e6%8f%90%e6%a1%88) というメタタグを作って付け、今後はタイトルではなくタグとして提案の種類を表してもらうと良いのではと思いました。

このような仕組みにしても良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

特に反対意見が無いようだったので、今日ふたつのメタタグを作成し、今までの投稿にすべてタグ付けしておきました。