# 残っている「タグシノニム」を「タグの別名」に揃えたい

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

["タグの別名 (シノニム)" 一覧ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)などのページに「タグ シノニム」「タグの別名」が混在しているので、「(タグの)別名」に揃えたいです。

**関連:**
[用語の変更：「タグシノニム」を「タグの別名」に変えませんか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1851)

---

この投稿は cubick さんの[こちらの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3213/19110)から分離したものです。