# 「○○にリンクされた質問」という翻訳

Tags: サポート, 翻訳

Traducir にある string で、"linked questions" というキーワードが使われているものがいくつかあります。

例：

- Unanswered Linked Questions
- Highest Voted Linked Questions
- Hot Linked Questions

一覧：https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5BLl%5Dinked%20%5BQq%5Duestion

これらは現状、

- ［未解決］にリンクされた質問
- ［得票数最多］にリンクされた質問
- ［今話題］にリンクされた質問

といった風に和訳されているのですが、これらの和訳が妥当なのか分かりません。

"linked questions" という言葉に関連して、このようなページが見つかりました:https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/11。特定の質問へリンクしている質問の一覧が見れるページで、この URL の質問 ID を置換すればそれぞれの質問について閲覧できます。質問ページの右サイドバーに表示される「リンク集」下部に「リンクされている質問をさらに表示...」というリンクが表示され、この URL に誘導されることもあるようです。例：[Stack Overflowの専門用語](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11)。

しかし、単純な "linked questions" 以外の用法が見つかっていません。"Unanswered Linked Questions" というのは「［未解決］にリンクされた質問」というよりかは「未解決の質問であり、かつ、多くリンクされている質問」みたいな意味ではないかと思ったのですが……。

どこでこの string が使われているかが分かれば、どう訳せば良いのかもはっきりします。これらの string はどこで使われていて、どのように訳すべきなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

該当の文字列はそれぞれ**ページのタイトル**として使用されているようです。
(ページを開いて、ブラウザのタブを確認してください)

以下の二つは恐らく全サイトで共通です。

- Highest Voted Linked Questions | [得票数最多] にリンクされた質問
- Hot Linked Questions | [今話題] にリンクされた質問

"Unanswered Linked Questions" についてはサイトによって対応が違いました。

- SOjaやSOでの「未解決」タブは、サイト全体での未解決な質問一覧にリンクされています。
- 一方で MSE や Ask Ubuntu など幾つかのサイトでは、URLの末尾で`?sort=unanswered`の形式でパラメータとして渡されています。

  例:
      https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/79347?sort=unanswered
      https://askubuntu.com/questions/linked/17823?sort=unanswered

なお、SOjaでもURLの末尾に`?sort=unanswered`を付け加えれば "Unanswered Linked Questions" のページを表示することができました。

---

訳についてはリンクが双方向なので悩ましいですが、代わりに「参照している/された」とかでもいいのかなぁと思いました。