# スタック・オーバーフロー 専門用語の和訳一覧

Tags: 討議, サポート, 翻訳, よくある質問の案, 専門用語

スタック・オーバーフローにはたくさんの専門用語があり、時々翻訳に迷います。

そこで、この FAQ で最新の和訳一覧を管理しましょう。[Traducir](https://ja.traducir.win/)で翻訳提案をする際などに参照できればと思います。

[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Comment: 今後ヘルプセンターの内容についてもこちらの和訳で統一していく、という認識で良いでしょうか？（[回答が「承認された」とはどういう意味ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)の「承認」など）

Comment: いくつか揺れている翻訳に関しては、揺れているものを列挙した上で、統一する必要があれば別途メタ投稿で統一していけば良いかなあと個人的には考えています。

Answer (score 5):

専門用語の和訳一覧です。追加や提案がございましたら直接編集をお願いします。

| 品詞 | 英語 | 和訳 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 動詞 | Accept | 承認 |
| 名詞 | Accepted Answer | 承認済みの回答 |
| 名詞 | Active | 有効 |
| 名詞 | Bounty | 懸賞/懸賞金 |
| 動詞 | Bounty | 懸賞金を付与する |
| 名詞 | Close Vote | クローズ票 |
| 名詞 | Closed Question | クローズされた質問 |
| 動詞 | Close a Question | 質問をクローズする |
| 名詞 | Downvote | マイナス投票 |
| 動詞 | Downvote | マイナス投票する |
| 名詞 | Flag | 通報 |
| 動詞 | Flag | 通報する |
| 名詞 | Merge | マージ |
| 名詞 | Peer Review | レビュー |
| 名詞 | Pending | 保留中 |
| 動詞 | Place in a Queue | レビュー待ちになる |
| 名詞 | Privileges | 権限 |
| 名詞 | Reputation | 信用度 |
| 名詞 | Reputation Change | 信用度の変化 |
| 名詞 | Reputation Decrease | 信用度の減少 |
| 名詞 | Reputation Increase | 信用度の増加 |
| 動詞 | Start Bounty | 懸賞/懸賞金を提示する |
| 名詞 | Suggested Edit | 提案された編集[内容]/編集案 |
| 動詞 | Suggest an Edit | 編集を提案する |
| 名詞 | Synonym | 別名 |
| 名詞 | Tag Synonyms | タグの別名 |
| 名詞 | Upvote | プラス投票 |
| 動詞 | Upvote | プラス投票する |
| 名詞 | Vote | 投票 |
| 動詞 | Vote | 投票する |
| 動詞 | Vote to Close | クローズ投票する |

Comment: "# of Renames" は特殊な例だし、"Last" もこれだけで "最終更新" としてしまうのは乱暴かなと思います。まとめるのは「頻出だけど訳に迷いそうなもの」に絞った方がよさそうです。

Comment: 専門用語っぽくないものを削除してみました。