# 改版履歴の編集サマリーで長いURLがはみ出す

Tags: バグ, デザイン

[専門用語の和訳一覧](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3502/32986) の [改版履歴](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3502/5) を見ていたところ、編集サマリーとして記入されていた長い URL の折り返しがされておらず、はみ出していることに気づきました。

[image: 編集サマリーのURLが折り返されず横に並んでいる要素と重なっており、親要素からはみ出している]

より長い URL だった場合は本来不要な横スクロールバーが生じるといった問題があるので、以下のように折り返されていたほうが見た目としては良いと思います。

[image: 編集サマリーのURLが折り返されており、URLは所定の位置に収まっている]

Comment: Firefox では折り返して表示されるので、ブラウザ固有の問題な気がします。 (試した範囲では Chromium 系のブラウザでのみ発生)

Comment: MSE にも報告してみました。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361838