# メタの既にあるタグ

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, タグ

メタでは「バグ」、「討議」、「機能の要求」と「サポート」等を変えるのがかなり複雑です。開発者に頼まないといけないので、ここですべてをリストアップして、一括で更新します。

```
bug                 ：バグ
discussion          ：討議
feature-request     ：機能の要求
support             ：サポート
community-ads       ：コミュニティ広告
faq                 ：faq
featured            ：注目
status-bydesign     ：状況：意図的
status-completed    ：状況：完了
status-declined     ：状況：謝絶
status-deferred     ：状況：延期
status-norepro      ：状況：再現不可能
status-planned      ：状況：計画中
status-reproduced   ：状況：再現可能
status-review       ：状況：検討中
accepted-answer     ：質問者選択
answers             ：回答
asking-questions    ：質問
badges              ：バッジ
bounty              ：報奨
chat                ：チャット
closed-questions    ：閉鎖済み質問
close-reasons       ：閉鎖理由
comments            ：コメント
community-wiki      ：コミュニティ・ウィキ
data-dump           ：データまとめ
data-explorer       ：データ・エクスプローラー
deleted-questions   ：削除済み質問
design              ：デザイン
down-votes          ：否定票
editing             ：編集
etiquette           ：作法
exact-duplicates    ：複製質問
favorites           ：気に入り質問
flagging            ：警告通知
formatting          ：フォーマット
hyperlinks          ：ハイパーリンク
interesting-tags    ：興味深いタグ
login               ：ログイン
markdown            ：マークダウン
meta                ：meta
migration           ：質問移動
moderation          ：仲裁者
new-users           ：新ユーザ
notifications       ：通知
openid              ：openid
profile-page        ：プロフィル
questions           ：質問
recent-activity     ：最近の活動
reputation          ：評判点数
retagging           ：タグ変更
rss                 ：rss
search              ：検索
site-promotion      ：サイト促進
specific-question   ：特定の質問
stackexchange       ：stackexchange
statistics          ：統計
tagging             ：タグの付け方
tags                ：タグ
tag-synonyms        ：タグの異名
unanswered-questions：未回答質問
up-votes            ：肯定票
user-accounts       ：ユーザー・アカウント
user-interface      ：ユーザー・インターフェース
users               ：ユーザー
votes, voting       ：投票
vote-to-close       ：質問閉鎖の投票
```

残念ながら、現在「：」文字は使えません。システムは認識しないです。

Comment: まさに、[元締めメタのまとめ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37424/157841)をみていたところでした

Answer (score 3):

junichi itoから頂いた提案は下記にあります：

```
bug                 ：バグ
discussion          ：ディスカッション
feature-request     ：新機能のリクエスト / 機能要望
support             ：サポート
community-ads       ：コミュニティ広告
faq                 ：FAQ
featured            ：注目中 / 注目
status-bydesign     ：仕様通り / 意図的 / 意図的仕様
status-completed    ：完了
status-declined     ：却下
status-deferred     ：実施延期 / 見合わせ中
status-norepro      ：再現せず
status-planned      ：計画中
status-reproduced   ：再現あり
status-review       ：検討中
accepted-answer     ：ベストアンサー
answers             ：回答
asking-questions    ：質問の仕方
badges              ：バッジ
bounty              ：bounty / お礼
chat                ：チャット
closed-questions    ：クローズされた質問
close-reasons       ：クローズされた理由 / クローズ理由
comments            ：コメント
community-wiki      ：コミュニティWiki
data-dump           ：データダンプ
data-explorer       ：データエクスプローラー
deleted-questions   ：削除された質問
design              ：デザイン
down-votes          ：downvote
editing             ：編集中 / 編集の仕方
etiquette           ：エチケット / マナー
exact-duplicates    ：重複した質問
favorites           ：お気に入り
flagging            ：問題フラグ / 通報
formatting          ：フォーマット / 書式設定
hyperlinks          ：ハイパーリンク
interesting-tags    ：お気に入りのタグ
login               ：ログイン
markdown            ：markdown
meta                ：Meta Stack Overflow / メタ
migration           ：質問の移動
moderation          ：調整 / モデレーション
new-users           ：新しいユーザー / 新規ユーザー
notifications       ：通知
openid              ：openid
profile-page        ：プロフィールページ
questions           ：質問
recent-activity     ：最近の活動
reputation          ：reputation / 信用度
retagging           ：再タグ付け
rss                 ：rss / フィード
search              ：検索
site-promotion      ：プロモーション / サイトの宣伝 / 宣伝活動
specific-question   ：特定の質問について
stackexchange       ：stackexchange
statistics          ：統計
tagging             ：タグ付け / タグの付け方
tags                ：タグ
tag-synonyms        ：類似のタグ / 同義のタグ
unanswered-questions：未回答の質問
up-votes            ：upvote
user-accounts       ：ユーザーアカウント
user-interface      ：ユーザーインターフェース
users               ：ユーザー
votes               ：投票
voting              ：投票の仕方
vote-to-close       ：クローズ投票する / クローズ投票
```