# メタにおけるシステムタグの翻訳案を提案してください

Tags: 討議, 完了

翻訳をしてくれた[@cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)に感謝します。

---

メタにおけるにすべてのシステムタグを日本語で付けるのは素晴らしいことだと思います。
タグのリストを作成しました。それぞれの翻訳を提案してもらえますか？

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) → [討議](/questions/tagged/%e8%a8%8e%e8%ad%b0)
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) → [バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0)
- [support](/questions/tagged/support) → [サポート](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b5%e3%83%9d%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88)
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) → [機能の要求](/questions/tagged/%e6%a9%9f%e8%83%bd%e3%81%ae%e8%a6%81%e6%b1%82)
- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) → [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)
- [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) → [注目](/questions/tagged/%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae)
- [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) → [コミュニティ広告](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9f%e3%83%a5%e3%83%8b%e3%83%86%e3%82%a3%e5%ba%83%e5%91%8a)
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) →
- [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) →
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) →
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) →
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) →
- [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) →
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) →
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) →

すべてのタグの翻訳ができ次第、開発者にそれらをサイトの設定に追加するよう依頼します。
キーボードレイアウトを切り替える理由はもうありません。 :)

---

タグの種類について念のため補足します。

- [バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0) など輪郭が太いグレーのタグ: 質問時の必須タグ。
  質問時にも表示されますが、いずれかのタグを1つ以上指定する必要があります。
- [交流会](/questions/tagged/%e4%ba%a4%e6%b5%81%e4%bc%9a) など輪郭が薄いグレーのタグ: 通常のタグ。
  上記の必須タグと合わせて、質問(投稿)を分類するために一般ユーザーが自由に割り当てまたは提案することができます。
- [注目](/questions/tagged/%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae) など赤文字のタグ: モデレーターのみが指定可能なタグ。
  一部の翻訳対応などを除いて、例えば「バグ修正の要求」に対して対応できるのは(社員の)モデレーターだけなので、割り当てできるのもモデレーターに限定されています。

なお、これらの説明はタグの一覧ページにある凡例で参照することもできます(ちょっとわかりづらいですね)。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Note: We have already [translated](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/16/19110)&used [discussion], [bug], [support], [feature-request], [featured] and [community-ads]. \[faq\] is a well-known word also in Japanese. I don't know whether our Community wants to translate [status-xxx] tags, or not.

Comment: @nekketsuuu Thank you a lot! Please let me know if you want to see the tags in Japanese. I will be glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

**既に別名(シノニム)を設定済み、または代替のタグがあるもの**

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) → [討議](/questions/tagged/%e8%a8%8e%e8%ad%b0)
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) → [バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0)
- [support](/questions/tagged/support) → [サポート](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b5%e3%83%9d%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88)
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) → [機能の要求](/questions/tagged/%e6%a9%9f%e8%83%bd%e3%81%ae%e8%a6%81%e6%b1%82)
- [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) → [注目](/questions/tagged/%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae)
- [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) → [コミュニティ広告](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9f%e3%83%a5%e3%83%8b%e3%83%86%e3%82%a3%e5%ba%83%e5%91%8a)

**新たな翻訳案**

[payanecoさんの翻訳案](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3064)を採用しました！

- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) → [よくある質問](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f)
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) → [完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)
- [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) → [再現性なし](/questions/tagged/%e5%86%8d%e7%8f%be%e6%80%a7%e3%81%aa%e3%81%97)
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) → [仕様](/questions/tagged/%e4%bb%95%e6%a7%98)
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) → [却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b)
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) → [対応予定](/questions/tagged/%e5%af%be%e5%bf%9c%e4%ba%88%e5%ae%9a)
- [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) → [再現済](/questions/tagged/%e5%86%8d%e7%8f%be%e6%b8%88)
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) → [調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad)
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) → [延期](/questions/tagged/%e5%bb%b6%e6%9c%9f)

Comment: status-xxx系は以前個人的に訳出しようと思ったことがあるのですが、ハイフンを上手く訳せなかった記憶があります。

Comment: タグを設定できるのはモデレータに限られることを考えると、シンプルに「完了済み」等にしてしまってもいいのかな？とは思います。

Comment: `faq`についても、あえて訳すなら「よくある質問(とその回答)」になりますが、FAQのままでも十分伝わるのかなと。

Comment: はい、\[faq\]は\[faq\]のままで良いかなと思っていました。

Answer (score 6):

- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) faq | よくある質問
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) 完了
- [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) 再現性なし | 未再現
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) 仕様通り | 仕様
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) 却下
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) 対応予定
- [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) 再現済
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) 調査中 | レビュー
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) 要検討 | 延期

システムタグの翻訳を提案します。

個人的には赤枠タグとそれ以外の違いが分からないので、タグWikiなどのリンク先で赤枠の説明をしてくださるとありがたいです。

[過去の翻訳案](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2626)やコメントに従い、翻案を変更しました。
修正前のものが必要であれば履歴をご参照願います。

Comment: 赤いタグなどの種類についての説明を元質問に追記してみましたので参考にしてください。

Comment: @cubick 大変参考になります。ありがとうございます。

Comment: とても良いと思います。個人的には「頻出質問」より「よくある質問」の方がよく見るし分かり良いのかな？と思ったりします。

Comment: @Sieg ありがとうございます。『よくある質問』の方が分かりやすいですね。しかし実は技術者向けサイトのメタ質問タグですのでfaqはfaqのままで良いとも思っています(回答者がこんなコメントを返してすみません)

Comment: みなさまへ：「ステータス-xxx」の形ではなくても、よろしいでしょうか？
以前にYuki Inoueさんが投稿くださっていた翻訳案は[こちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2626/14055)ですm_ _m。

Comment: 個人的には赤枠で差別化できているので無くてもシステム的なお知らせなんだなと分かるかなぁと思いました。でも、元に寄せるなら付けてもいいのかもしれません。

Comment: 後出しで申し訳ありませんが、私の質問文にある「タグの説明文がしっかりしていると～」は、タグWikiの末尾にタグの種類が補足されていると分かりやすいのではないかという意図でした。タグの一覧ページにある凡例を読めば不要ですが、システムタグにも[必須タグ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%e8%a8%8e%e8%ad%b0/info)と同様に意味が明示されていると「なんで赤字なの？」と疑問に感じた一見さんがタグをクリックした時のヘルプになると感じます。

Comment: 正直なところ一般ユーザが「ステータス-xxx」の記述を読んで「ああこれはモデレータが対応状況を管理するためのシステムタグなのか」と直感することは難しいと思います。なので赤枠で差別化し、タグのリンク先で補足していれば「ステータス-」の接頭辞は不要ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 半分冗談ですが、「ステータス-」を訳出する必要があるけれども良い訳が見つからないならば「完了◆」のようにモデレータマークを付けると専用タグを連想しやすいかもしれませんね。人によっては某少年漫画のハンターを連想するかもしれませんけれども。

Comment: @payaneco コミュニティwikiの方に、この翻訳案を元にした翻訳を載せてみました。ありがとうございます！！ https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3062

Comment: nekketsuuu 採用ありがとうございます！