# メタ版サイドバーの「よくある質問」に質問の一覧が表示されていない

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン, メタ

### 不具合事象

メタ版サイドバーの「よくある質問」が表示されなくなっています。

#### 不具合発生前

[image: サイドバーの「よくある質問」が表示されている]

#### 不具合発生後

[image: サイドバーの「よくある質問」が表示されていない]

---

### 原因

この不具合はシステムタグを日本語に翻訳した時期に発生したため、この変更が関係していると考えられます。

- [メタにおけるシステムタグの翻訳案を提案してください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061)

Comment: We'll investigate this as part of our bug duty rotation, but unfortunately it may be a while before we get to it. Thanks for the report!（こちらをバグデューティローテーションの一環として調査しますが、残念ながら少し時間がかかりそうです。ご報告くださりどうもありがとうございます！）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「よくある質問」の一覧がメタサイト右側のサイドバーに再び表示されるようになりました。

注意：広告ブロッカーが有効な場合は表示されないことがあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]