# product-discovery タグを和訳したい

Tags: 機能の要求, タグ

新しく [product-discovery](/questions/tagged/product-discovery) というモデレーター専用タグが追加されました。

経緯：[New Feedback Tag – [product-discovery]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346894/341401)

スタック・オーバーフロー メタでは[モデレーター専用タグは和訳されるようになった](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/19110)ため、このタグにも和訳をつけたいです。

以下、経緯としてリンクした記事の意訳です。

---

プロダクトチームは現在 end-to-end な製品開発サイクルに注目し、サイクルの中で皆さんに共有できるマイルストーンがプロジェクトのどこにあるのかを考えています。皆さんのメタ・コミュニティにおけるフィードバックは貴重なものであると認識しており、フィードバックを組み込むためにも早い段階からアイディアを共有したいと思っています。混乱を避けたり期待を適切な程度に抑えたりするため、それぞれのマイルストーンやステージにおいて期待するフィードバックの形をなるべく明確にする予定です。たとえば Discovery ステージにある機能は決定するまでに何回かデザインを変えていくことになるため、Build ステージに至るまでにフィードバックを組み込む余地がより多く存在します。Build ステージの終盤で機能を変えるのにはコストがかかる上、ユーザーに受け入れてもらえるかのテストも必要です。

プロジェクトが今どのステージにあるのかを明確にし、皆さんに適切な程度の期待を持っていただくため、いくつか新しいタグを導入しようとしています（全部で2、3個くらいです）。まずは全てのメタサイトにおいて [product-discovery] というモデレーター専用タグを作りました。このタグは Discovery フェーズにある、製品や設定変更に関わるものを共有する際、スタッフによって使われます。多くの場合、方向性や達成したいことは決まっていて、その上でどうするか調べたり見つけたりする時間があるというときに使われます。

それぞれの投稿においてはなるべくはっきり説明するように努力し、皆さんの考えを共有してもらえるようにします。なるべく皆さんのご意見には反応するようにしますが、単独のフィードバックや投票しかないご意見については実装に時間を割きづらいことをご了承ください。

このやり方が私たちと皆さんの関係を再構築する助けになると思っています。ご協力に感謝いたします。

Comment: 上記の meta 上では、コミュニティにとっての、このタグの表す意味が、まだ確定していないように見えています。それが確定してから議論するのでも、遅くはないかもと思っています。

Comment: 「product-discovery」や「discovery phase」の良い訳が見つからず困っています。とりあえずタグ wiki については一旦「ディスカバリーフェーズ」として訳出されましたが、より良い訳を募集中です。 https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54380339#54380339

Comment: 元の product-discovery がよい名前ではないと感じます。言わんとするニュアンス自体は分かるのですが、Product (製品) という呼び名は **開発者視点** での捉え方のように感じます。一方、我々ユーザーが利用しているのはあくまで **Webサービス** であり、この辺りに剥離があります。