# 「faq案」タグを「よくある質問の案」タグにし、用語の変更に追従させたい

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求, 完了, タグ, タグの付け替えの提案

[faq案](/questions/tagged/faq%e6%a1%88) というメタのタグがありますが、「FAQ」という言い方は [メタにおけるシステムタグの翻訳案を提案してください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/19110) によって「よくある質問」に変わりました。

このため「faq案」というタグも「よくある質問の案」というタグに付け替えたいです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

特に反対意見が無くプラス票のみが集まったため、タグのマージ機能を使ってこの付け替えを行いました。

```
updating post history, 22 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 17 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 17 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'faq案': [faq案] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 17
tag remapping of [よくある質問の案] and [faq案] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym faq案 -> よくある質問の案 was approved!
```