# コミュニティウィキの編集サマリーがはみ出ていて最後まで見えない

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

サンプル: [スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%81%B8%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D)

スクショ:

[image: はみでている]

確認環境: Google Chrome 38.0.2125.111 / Mac OS X 10.10 / Retina

Comment: デザイナーが改善したと言っています。これは今でも再現できますか？

Comment: @jmac まだ再現します。(キャッシュを無効にしてリロードしました。) メタにはまだCSSが反映されていないとか? (メインでは未確認)

Comment: 環境を教えてくれますか？

Comment: @jmac 質問本文に確認環境を追記しました

Comment: @jmac 今見たら改善していました (きちんと改行されるようになっていた)